# Python: Creating a Grid of X,Y coordinates and corresponding calculated Z values to result in a 3D array of XYZ

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, xyz

I have a function that calculates a z value from a given x and y coordinate. I then want to combine these values together to get a 3D array of x,y,z. I'm attempting to do this with the code below:

```
#import packages

import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#Define function to calculate z over a grid
def func(X, Y, x, y, Q):
    return (Q / (2 * np.pi)) * np.arctan((y-Y)/(x-X))

#For initial testing just defining the IW explicitly, last step will be to read the input file and pull this data
X1=2417743.658
Y1=806346.704
Q1=5
X2=2417690.718
Y2=806343.693
Q2=5
X3=2417715.221
Y3=806309.685
Q3=5

#initiate the XY grid
xi = np.linspace(2417675,2417800,625)
yi = np.linspace(806300,806375,375)

#mesh the grid in to x,y space
x,y = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

#calculate the values over the grid at every x,y using the defined function above
zi = (func(X1,Y1,x,y,Q1)+func(X2,Y2,x,y,Q2)+func(X3,Y3,x,y,Q3))

#reshape the xy space into 3d space - when i plot this grid it looks correct
xy = np.array([[(x, y) for x in xi] for y in yi])

#reshape z into 3d space -  this appears to be where the issue begins
z = np.array(zi).reshape(xy.shape[0],xy.shape[1], -1)

#combined xyz into a single grid
xyz = np.concatenate((xy, z), axis = -1)

# Create figure and add axis
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

img = ax.imshow((xyz*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

output:
[image: output]

I do get an XYZ array and when i print it the values appear to be mapping correctly, however when I plot the data, it shows the y values "upside down" essentially. This is what the output should look like but "flipped" over the x over axis. Additionally the axes show node numbers and not the X,Y values. I want the 0,0 point to be the lower left hand corner like cartesian coordinates, and each x,y have a corresponding z which is calculated from that given x,y. I know there must be an easier way to go about this. Does anyone know a better way? or maybe what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: read the documentation of `imshow` it has the answers to all your questions. (the issue is not in how you compute your data, but how you display it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option for ax.imshow() that allows to specify the origin point.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

> origin{'upper', 'lower'}, default: rcParams["image.origin"] (default:
> 'upper') Place the [0, 0] index of the array in the upper left or
> lower left corner of the Axes. The convention (the default) 'upper' is
> typically used for matrices and images.
>
> Note that the vertical axis points upward for 'lower' but downward for
> 'upper'.
>
> See the origin and extent in imshow tutorial for examples and a more
> detailed description.

Try to modify to this:

```
img = ax.imshow((xyz*255).astype(np.uint8), origin='lower')
```

For the axis labels they can be changed with the following commands

```
ax.set_xticks(LIST_OF_INDICIES)
ax.set_xticklabels(LIST_OF_VALUES)
```

Comment: if you are to post an answer, you may as well answer all the question, i.e. how to fix the axes range too...

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. 
I did not have an account with rep so I could not just post as comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That did work for the origin. I still get node number though instead of the X,Y cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @KristianGræseFleron Thanks!